# Unable to reach container webserver from host localhost

Tags: docker, containers, iptables

Using Docker v 17.03.1-ce, on a linux mint machine, i'm unable to reach the container web server (container port 5000)  with my browser (localhost port 9000) on the host.

Container launched with command :

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9000:5000 --name myContainer imageName
```

- I started by checking that the server (flask) on my container was properly launched. It's launched.
- I wanted to check that the server was working properly, so in the container, using curl, i sent a GET request on localhost, port 5000. The server returned the web page

So, the server is working, therefore the issue lies somewhere in the communication between container and host.

I checked iptables, but am not sure what to make of it:

**sudo iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**sudo iptables -t nat -L -n**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.18.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9000 to:172.17.0.2:5000
```

**Expected result** : using my browser, with url "localhost:9000", i can receive the homepage sent from the container, through port 5000.

**edit**: Adding docker logs and docker ps

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
59a20248c5b2        apptest             "python3 src/jboos..."   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:9000->5000/tcp   jboost
```

**sudo docker logs jboost**

```
 * Serving Flask app "jboost_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 310-292-856
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jul/2019 04:12:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**edit 2**: adding results for curl localhost:9000 on host machine
So when connecting with my web browser, the connection doesn't work, but curl gives a more specific message:

```
curl localhost:9000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Did you try `curl http://localhost:9000` on the host machine? Also try with your IP address.

Comment: docker logs, docker ps?

Comment: @Ntwobike, the logs and docker ps have been added.

Comment: @PrakashKrishna, curl shows : curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer .

Comment: May be Port is being used by some other service, Use some random port number for port mapping other than 9000 and try that

Comment: @Prasanth, thank. I found the issue. In my container, the flask server was, by default, only accepting requests from localhost. I needed to specify that it should answer to queries from any ip, by specifying app.run(host='0.0.0.0') .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this post : https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/dockerized-flask-connection-reset-by-peer

The Docker networking and port forwarding were working correctly. The problem was with my **flask** server. It seems that by default, the server is configured to only accept requests from local host.

When launching your flash server, with the "run" command, you must specify host='0.0.0.0' , so that any ip can be served.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```